# How to handle store procedure outputs in .NET 6 Web API using EF Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am using EF Core 6 in my .NET 6 Web API. My store procedure is returning 2 types of output. In case of no results found for given inputs combination, it is returning 1. If records found, its returning result set.
In code I have a lines as below

`var result = _dbContext.CustomerModelDTO.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec spName {input1}, {input2}"); return result;`

Above code works find when it return result set but when it returns 1 in case of no data found, I am getting error as CustomerID column not found in a result set. This is because I am getting 1 not empty result set. How would I handle this scenario.
Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a simple `try-catch` block on the exact type of exception thrown when no data is found

Comment: The variable results is an array and best way of testing when no output is returned from linq is to check for count > 0.